# Is it safe to use CallContext.Logical[set/get]Data when you're using .NET ThreadPool threads?

Tags: .net, threadpool, thread-local-storage

I understand that the LogicalCallContext, which is what is set using these methods, flows to new threads, if you use like ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem. The question is tho, when the thread that has this object is re-used by the threadpool, does the logical call context get reset? or do I end up with state that doesn't belong to me?

**Couple of mentions:**

- From what I can tell from the .net source code, the entire Execution context is cloned whenever you enqueue a new task to the thread pool. This context includes security related stuff as well, so I would think that if the context is not reset, this would be a major no-no.
- In a test app, it seems to work fine, even if I set the state from the context to a dummy value after I'm done with it, just to make it more likely that upon re-use, I would have a bad state.
- I'm not using any async programming, windows forms / WPF or anything like that. Just plain .NET api calls (and none that start with 'Begin...')
- I understand that simply using Thread Local Storage, that would just not work, cuz that is NOT cleared when a thread switches over.

Thanks

Comment: You are using this feature off-label, LCC is a Remoting detail.  It works because the SecurityContext needs to flow to the tp thread.  A CAS feature, deprecated at .NET 4.0.  You can't get a warranty here.

Comment: Thanks Hans. In that case I'd probably not go with this. I imagine I can do the same thing by decorating QueueUserWorkItem with a try/finally in which I set/clear some thread local state myself, and then it should be just a global replace (almost).

Comment: Btw, if you make the comment an answer I will mark the questions as answered ...

Answer (score 0):

Edited in 2020: After resorting to this for a large legacy project recently (basically a web server), it worked without any issues.

Can't quite say I recommend it, but if it saves you from impossible refactoring of a large code base, to 'carry' state around, it may be worth a shot.

I'm more or less just answering with what Hans replied.

> You are using this feature off-label, LCC is a Remoting detail. It
>   works because the SecurityContext needs to flow to the tp thread. A
>   CAS feature, deprecated at .NET 4.0. You can't get a warranty here.

It seems some technologies from MS also use CallContext, like Entity Framework 6, but the exact details are unclear (do they spwan threasds or not, do they use async programming).

So, the answer should be NO, it's not safe to do use it in this fashion.